# Autolayout change height of the view when app starts

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, storyboard, autolayout

I have `UIViewController` on storyboard.
On the image you can see top gray is simple `UIView` while bellow is `UITableView`.
And I set uiview to be 150 height.
I use autolayout.
Problem is that when I run app on iPhone 6 uiview height is about 40% of the `UIViewController`.
From some reason it's height is larger than 150.
Can somebody explain me how can I setup view so I have UIView always the same size?
[image: example]

Comment: when you run the app does it give any constraints warning?

Comment: No there are no constraint warnings.

Comment: can you please add an image with the view constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your view height....you can not give static height.... see the images and check out where you missing out....

[image]

and the o/p is in 4.7 , 5.5 , and 4 inch is

[image]

for all the height of view is looking same....that is of 150 height

Comment: Thanks this did the trick. Can you just make something clear to me. When I add new viewcontroller to the storyboard I always change `Simulated Metrics > Size > to iPhone 4"` Do I need to do this or it's better to leave it as `Inferred`? What is the practice?

Comment: The best practice is you should always prefer wAhA metrics for auto layout...it gives you exact idea for your view....

Answer (score 0):

Have you included an iPhone 6 launch image? My guess is that the iPhone is resizing up based on the resolution of the 4" screen. Include either a static launch image, or a dynamic, xib-based one, and I think that should fix your problem.

Comment: Yes I have launch image. All views are fine except this. I feel like uitable pull uiview bottom down somehow. I have tried all constraint magic and don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Do you have launch images for the iPhone 6 specifically? Having just one launch image won't do it. Could you also provide a screenshot of the view when on an iPhone 5s and on the iPhone 6?

Comment: Yes I have launch images in all sizes. It is same on 5s and 6. In all screens somehow uiview getting larger in height.